# Building table layout dynamically at run time from XML

Tags: android, xml

New to android, I would like to have a view like below with actual values.

[image]

My code to dummy values is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:background="#607D8B"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Title" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Due On" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="#ECEFF1"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Access to Knowledge" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="12 Feb 2016" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Renew" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="#ECEFF1"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Achivement" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="16 Feb 2016" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Renew" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:background="#ECEFF1"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="God of small things" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="22 Feb 2016" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Renew" />
    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:text="Renew all" />

</TableLayout>
```

I am getting the values from XML from webservices and parsing it to show in my table view.

I am using DocumentBuilderFactory to parse my XML. Here my XML file is in String str.

```
 builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                            InputSource src = new InputSource();
                            src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(str));

                            Document doc = builder.parse(src);
                            String title = `doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();`
```

Normally I use

```
TitleTxt.setText("Title: " + title);

PublisherTxt.setText("Publisher: " + publisher)
```

to show the results in my view.

I have multiple questions:
Q1 what modifications are needed in layout file to show - actual values and not the dummy values?
Q2 how to get the array values in XML parsing to show in my layout file?
Q3 how to show the XML parsed results in my table view - dynamically at runtime?

These are related queries, so had to put in the same question. Some of it may sound simple, but being new to Android, I am not able to figure out. Also tried to find a sample code to do it but could not find. Not sure if I am using the right keywords to search for what I am looking for.

Any links to sample code or which exact keywords to look for to search my issue solution or suggestions will also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest using `RecyclerView` instead.

Comment: Tried that too, but did not work. Looking for some detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add new Views to another **at runtime**, you can use the **View.add** method. So, in order to make the above table "dynamic", you can alter your layout file to just contain the TableLayout. And later, at runtime you programmatically add TableRows to the TableLayout.
Basically, there are **two options** how to add a TableRow then.
**First**, you can construct your TableRow, e.g.:

```
TextView tvTitle = new TextView(...);
TextView tvDueOn = new TextView(...);
Button btnRenew = new TextView(...);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(...);
tr.add(tvTitle);
tr.add(tvDueOn);
tr.add(btnRenew);
TableLayout lytTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(...);
lytTable.add(tr);
```

This is just a minimal version, but with adding the views weight, layout_width and layout_height, you can achieve this.

**Second**, you can design your TableRow in a layout XML file, which you can then load and add to the TableLayout at runtime using LayoutInflater.

lytTableRow.xml

```
<TableRow
    android:id="+@id/lytTableRow"
    android:background="#607D8B"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="+@id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="+@id/tvDueOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="+@id/btnRenew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />
</TableRow>
```

code in Activity

```
TableLayout lytTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.lytTable);
View tableRow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lytTableRow, null);
TextView tvTitle = (TextView)tableRow.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
TextView tvDueOn = (TextView)tableRow.findViewById(R.id.tvDueOn);
Button btnRenew = (Button)tableRow.findViewById(R.id.btnRenew);
tvTitle.setText(...);
```

Both code-parts can be put into a loop for instance, in order to add your multiple rows - but pay attention to set **tags**/ids to your views using view.setTag in order to be able to distinguish them later in the Button click listener for instance.

Concerning the data, depending on what kind of XML parser you use, you can loop through every item in the data and add them to your TableLayout using one of the options shown above. According to your question, you use a DOM parser. You can loop through the items using a NodeList retrieved from `doc.getElementsByTagName("parentnodename")` where parentnodename is the element name which contains "title", "dueon" etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try this.